# Install Ubuntu Desktop or Server in Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, installation, server

I was planning to install the latest Ubuntu 11.10. I mostly plan to install the server edition. I am having a 4GB ram and a 500gb hdd on an intel core 2 duo processor which I want to make good use of.

Apart from hosting a site on the server , I'm not sure about what are the other advantages of installing the server edition over the desktop. I plan to use the m/c for development purposes also.

Can you kindly provide me more info on the pros and cons of using the server/desktop edition(specifically for Ubuntu 11.10) so that I could better decide which would suit my requirements before proceeding with the installation.

I did have a look at [What's the difference between the server version and the desktop version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31081/whats-the-difference-between-the-server-version-and-the-desktop-version) for more info, although useful, its not detailed and not specific to the Ubuntu version I'm referring to.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between the server version and the desktop version?  ](http://askubuntu.com/questions/31081/whats-the-difference-between-the-server-version-and-the-desktop-version)

Comment: 11.10 is an old unsupported version, do you mean 13.10 ?

Comment: Thats an old question, not "off topic because about an EOL version".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no gui for the server edition

if you plan to use it as a daily workspace and you're not already fully familiar with command only, you'd better install the desktop edition.You can also host a website by using the desktop edition decided by which web server you're using.

btw, install x64 version will make good use of your 4GB RAM,:-)

Comment: 32-bit Linux can totally make use of 4Gb RAM, it's absolutely not a reason to choose a 64-bit version.

Comment: Hi Sevan, Thanks for your answer.. when one can host a site through their desktop edition, then for what specific reason would one prefer the server over the desktop version..? . I was reading that the bundled packages could would differ b/w the two versions..

Comment: yeah,u're right! The desktop version has many bundled packages and mostly are for GUI use. Besides, server version has LAMP in it, you don't need to reconfigure it by yourself.

Comment: btw, x86 version could read 2^32 unit at most. But your device such  as Graphics Card will occupy some memory, so it'll not fully use 4GB. x64 version is very popular nowadays, you can even add RAM later.

Comment: Seems like Desktop version would serve my purpose well.. I have a little confusion in now choosing between 32 and 64 bit.. any enlightenment on when to use what would be of great help.. The download link of Ubuntu 11.10(http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download) suggests 32 bit, however this link(https://help.ubuntu.com/community/32bit_and_64bit) seems to favor 64 bit.. Thanks..

Comment: The download link for Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit has an amd64 attached to the iso image available for download.. does that mean it will work only on amd processors..? I have an intel core 2 duo 2.2 ghz processor with a 64 bit OS.. will the iso download suit my system requirements.. I'm not aware of any Ruby on Rails apps/softwares which mandate 32 bit os.. do you have knowledge of any as such...? Thanks a lot..

Comment: the amd64 doesn't mean that it only works on amd processors, it also works fine on your core 2 processor.Here amd64 means it is a x64 architecture os.

Answer (score 1):

But if the computer you are installing on is a stand alone computer, and you plan on accessing the server from another computer it's wiser to use Ubuntu server. It doesn't install GNOME or any GUI or office programs just base Linux and the services you select at boot. It's also tends to be more secure.

Comment: Thanks satempler, Good point.. but the m/c on which I plan to do the setup is not at a remote location..