# Whats the difference between Ubuntu 11.10 and Ubuntu 11.10 Server Version?

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between the server version and the desktop version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31081/whats-the-difference-between-the-server-version-and-the-desktop-version)

I've just purchased the CD's from Ubuntu, I got a Ubuntu 11.10 and a Ubuntu 11.10 Server edition, is there a large difference between those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu is for everyday desktop use, Ubuntu Server is mainly for websites and has no graphical interface.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a big difference. Ubuntu Desktop (what I presume you're referring to as just "Ubuntu") is designed for everyday use on a standard desktop (or laptop) computer. It will have all the usual things you would expect from an operating system (office suite, browser, file manager, mouse, shiny graphics).

Ubuntu Server, on the other hand, is designed for servers. Because one rarely actually sits at the physical server, there is no graphical support included by default (ie. command line only). It will also be optimized for server support in other ways.