# What is the difference between 12.04 Desktop & 12.04 Server images

Tags: cd-image, distro-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between the server version and the desktop version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31081/whats-the-difference-between-the-server-version-and-the-desktop-version)

I've installed Ubuntu 11.10 Desktop version on my machine and I am using it as DHCP Server come Firewall. So if I can use Desktop version to configure any kind of machine we want then what is the purpose of Server version. Can we use Server version to install a simple Desktop? Does the Server version have some additional features?