# Trouble logging into newly installed Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, login

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04, but when I login it says `bryan@ubuntu:~$` and waits for me to type something. Is it supposed to be the password or is there a command I'm supposed to enter?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it Ubuntu Desktop or Server?

Comment: It sounds like you're at a virtual terminal instead of a GUI. Try pressing Ctrl+Alt+F7. This should take you to your standard GUI login screen.

Comment: @iBelieve Typically the only reasons someone isn't on tty7 after boot is if X11 isn't running at all. Running `startx` from the `$` prompt can sometimes help though.

Comment: @kelvinafox its ubuntu server. should i have used desktop? im installing it as the only os on the laptop..

Comment: i tried the other two suggestions with no success...

Comment: Because it is Ubuntu Server, it doesn't have a GUI at all. [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/31081/whats-the-difference-between-the-server-version-and-the-desktop-version) might help explain the differences between Ubuntu Desktop or Server.

Comment: so can will i be able to log in with ubuntu server or should i try ubuntu desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Since you see `bryan@ubuntu:~$`, you are already logged in. `bryan` is logged on at (`@`) the machine which you named `ubuntu`. The `~` shows where you are in the file system (~ means home folder) and the `$` means it is waiting for your commands.

Ubuntu Server is meant to be used from the command line (mainly for server administration). If you want to have a graphical environment (windows, icons, buttons, mouse pointer and such), you should install Ubuntu Desktop instead of Ubuntu Server.