# Web Server in Ubuntu Server vs in Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, apache2, webserver

Information about host:

- I have Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 installed in Hard Disk. (I don't use Windows).
- I had installed Apache Server (I don't remember when). When I test on Browser with the 192.168.1.3 address it works.

Information about guest:

- I have Ubuntu server 14.04 installed in VirtualBox.
- I have Bridge Connection for Guest Host.
- Lo 127.0.0.1, static address 192.168.1.10. Default-Gateway is home router: 192.168.1.1 for both.
- When I test Apache server from 192.168.1.10, it works too; How do I know?. Because I had done some basic editing to the .10 file in `/var/www/html` so I could differentiate them.

Now, if I had installed the Server in both places (Desktop computer and on the Server):

- I should use server as I assume is more powerful, but, wouldn't both get me to the creation of a dynamic website, administer it, edit it and so on?
- What are the differences?
- Does anybody know good tutorials I could use as a beginner?

Comment: This is not a good place to "gather opinions". since this is not a discussion forum.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between the server version and the desktop version?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/31081/whats-the-difference-between-the-server-version-and-the-desktop-version)

Answer (score 1):

There is NO difference what to use as a server. You can use either server or desktop Ubuntu version.

The difference of the versions is in pre-installed packages. The most obvious difference is that the server version does not have a GUI.