# Can I run Own Cloud on Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: server, cloud, storage

I would like to use One Cloud to set up my own personal cloud storage (unless anyone has a better solution). I would like to run it on Ubuntu desktop. Is this possible or does it have to be run from Ubuntu server?

Comment: although it is not the best idea, for sure it can be installed on both versions... it is even in the repositories (`sudo apt-get install owncloud`), but the [official repository](https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/owncloud/) would be the better way...!

Answer (score 0):

It should not make a difference, whether you use the server or the desktop version. The difference between them is mostly that the server version does not come with a gui and the gui related packages. 
See also:
[What's the difference between the server version and the desktop version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31081/whats-the-difference-between-the-server-version-and-the-desktop-version)