# 15.10 install and now my pc doesn't allow me to do anything, please help?

Tags: 15.10

Could someone please help me? I installed 15.10 yesterday and after it was done all I got was a black screen. Like the terminal black page. Someone told me to put in sudo startx and that got me to my desktop but with not one icon or time date, anything. So could someone please help me get back to normal, PLEASE? Thanks, martin

Comment: Did you install the Desktop or Server version? See -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/31081/whats-the-difference-between-the-server-version-and-the-desktop-version

Comment: I think I did! It asked if I would like to install the new version, so I clicked yes.

Comment: Server OR Desktop: which?

Answer (score 0):

you could try installing gnome- there may have been a problem with unity in the install? that command would be:

> sudo apt-get install gnome

and then do the startx thing?
Do you have any other information than that?

Comment: Information such as? Sorry not really a tech guy.

Comment: Have you got unity installed? Lightdm? Did you try the gnome thing? Also could you post the output of uname -a