# HP Prolient ML350 G5, should ubuntu server be installed?

Tags: xserver

Would it be wiser on the HP prolient ML350 G5 to run desktop ubuntu or Ubuntu Server? I am not familiar with the Server variant, any tips or ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between the server version and the desktop version?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/31081/whats-the-difference-between-the-server-version-and-the-desktop-version)

Answer (score 2):

The desktop version comes with a normal GUI including graphical standard applications.

The server version has **no graphical interface** but is only accessible through the command-line. It comes with a few server packages preinstalled.

---

Unless you are familiar with the Ubuntu command-line and have a reason not to use a graphical desktop, there is no reason for the average user to get the Ubuntu server version.