# what are the different between live server and Ubuntu Server also Ubuntu Desktop?

Tags: versions

I was read this part of the official documentation about ubuntu

> The basic steps to install Ubuntu Server Edition are the same as those for installing any operating system. Unlike the Desktop Edition, the Server Edition does not include a graphical installation program. The Live Server installer uses a text-based console interface which runs on the default virtual console.

they are said the **ubuntu server edition**  unlike the Desktop Edition

My question what are the different between Desktop Edition and Server edition and Live sever  or I am wrong can you orient me about the versions ?

I saw this answer in [quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Ubuntu-Desktop-and-Ubuntu-Server)

[live server](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-live-server.html.en)

Comment: Desktop versions include a DEsktop; ie. a GUI.  Server editions don't waste the resources and just use keyboard & screen (text).  If you skip this fact, they install different packages (biggest differences is still the DE/gui packages) but that's only part.  (https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-live-server.html.en)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the server and desktop install iso run as a live system.

The desktop includes a graphical desktop environment that you can use to web surf , email, edit text files, etc in addition to installing ubuntu with the desktop of choice. The desktop edition uses a graphical installer that runs on the desktop or you can run the installer without booting to a desktop.

The server is for installation only and runs a graphical installer that runs in a console, rather than a desktop. There is no live server environment, ie it does not run Apache or other servers, install media only.

See [What's the difference between the server version and the desktop version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31081/whats-the-difference-between-the-server-version-and-the-desktop-version) for additional details.