# General Questions about Linux Server set up

Tags: server

So I am just starting to buy and build the components for a modest linux server. It will be used for file management, organization, backup, VPN, media/streaming, possibly as a cloud and email server, maybe more. I am completely new to Linux but I have been using OSX most my life so some knowledge might cross over (probably not for what I am doing though)

I don't know much so forgive my ignorance. I only have two question at the moment:

How do you remotely control/access the server from a macbook pro or any OSX computer for that matter? Ideally I want to run a headless setup.

Is there much of a difference between Ubuntu desktop and Server?

I will probably be back at a latter date with many more questions once I boot up the machine. Thanks!

Comment: The difference between Desktop and Server is merely the list of packages - under the hood it's all the same. One great (free, easy) way to experiment with your first server is a Virtual Machine.

Comment: I would suggest using secure shell (SSH) from a terminal on your mac to your server. The main difference between server and desktop is no GUI for server, and way way less stuff running, getting in the way of server stuff. suggest [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/index.html) reference.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there much of a difference between Ubuntu desktop and Server?

No. A desktop install basically is a server with a desktop environment. systemd has 
a service that decides to show a login (aka. server version) or start the next service in line that creates the desktop session.

> How do you remotely control/access the server from a macbook pro or any OSX computer for that matter?

One way would be to install a SSH server. That way you can use the rcp (remote cp) like so:

```
rcp {files} {user:password}@{server-ip}/dir/to/copy/to
```

You can harden your system by also introducing ssh key pairs; that will lock anyone else out from accessing your server that did not synch the ssh key pairs.

What you ask for screams Google or Amazon cloud instance though and not a native server setup. That last one is far too time consuming and requires constant maintenance.

Comment: I agree that I don't really need my own server, but I want to get more into linux and computer knowledge in general so I think this would be the best way

Answer (score 0):

I hope you will enjoy the Linux environment, for your first question:

`You can easily access your all servers using ssh`

This will help you to configure ssh https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html.en

Your second answer difference between Ubuntu Desktop and server:
After Ubuntu 12.04, both Server and Desktop variants use the same kernel. Previously, Desktop and Server used different kernels. Because both Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server employ the same kernel, you can add any packages to either variant. This means that while default installation varies, you can customize your Ubuntu flavor accordingly.

check for brief: [What's the difference between the server version and the desktop version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31081/whats-the-difference-between-the-server-version-and-the-desktop-version)